# mfc-j825dw out of paper error but can print from another computer

Tags: printer

I moved and replugged ect my J825 printer. When I go to print the error message is out of paper" but there is paper AND my daughter can print from her Apple computer fine. So it does work but I cannot get it to work from my computer. I downloaded driver again with same out of paper error?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your PC is set to use the bypass tray in the printer (normally used for photo paper), whereas your daughter's is set for the main tray. Check the default tray on your PC and make sure it is set to the main paper tray.

Also, any existing Word documents may need to be changed, as Word saves paper settings with the document. To change it, open a document and go to Page Setup